# What causes this eggplant scar?

Tags: fruit

This eggplant fruit is featuring a big scar. What causes such a scratch? Is it a disease or maybe the fruit was hit and then it healed the crack? Is it correct to call it "Eggplant scab"?

[image]

Comment: do you know if that is where it lay on the ground? if not, it's probably due to the fruit being bred to grow very big compared to it's wild version.

Comment: @comprehensible - no idea. I got them from the fruit shop

Comment: perhaps someone threw a grenade near it when it was in the trenches, or it fell off it's motorbike when it was doing 30. even more likely is that it was in contact with planks/rods/a stem/the ground/some stones. perhaps try brushing it with a toothbrush.

Comment: return it and get a new eggplant

Comment: I like com.prehensibe's comment.Melons get cracks like this on the places where they sit on the ground. Melons are cucurbits too,this looks like it happened where the eggplant sat on the ground. Wash it off,it's still good.